# How to create multiple loop in archive page?

Tags: loop

This is my archive page codes

i want to avoid duplicate posts in 4th loop & i want to count post in 3rd loop

there are 4 loops

1 first loop count : 1 post

```
  <?php 
  $count = 1;
  if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();            
  if($count == 1) : ?>

 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

2 second loop - - count = 1 post

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $count = 1; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $count++; ?>
<?php if ($count == 2) : ?> 
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title=""><?php the_title(); ?>  </a>
```

3  third loop-- count = 5 post

```
<?php else : ?> 
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a> 
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>
<h1>Most Viewed News</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

4  loop -- count = rest of all post

```
<?php else : ?> 
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

-- ad count --

```
<?php if ( $count == 3 || $count == 5 ) : ?>
<?php dt_show_ads();?> 
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?> 
<?php $count++; ?> 
<?php endwhile; ?> 


<?php else : ?>
<div class="post">
<h2 class="archiveTitle"><?php _e('Sorry','linepress');?></h2>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid this kind of excess indentation at all costs, however this should work although I haven't tested it. Please let me know if there are syntax errors so that I can correct them.

```
<!-- first loop : 1 post -->        
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ):
        the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="" ><?php the_title(); ?></a> 

    <!-- second loop : 2 posts -->
    <?php
        if ( have_posts() ):
            $count = 0;
            while ( have_posts() ):
                the_post(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a> 

                <!-- third loop : 5 posts -->
            <?php
                if ( ++$count == 2 and have_posts() ):
                    $count = 0;
                    while ( have_posts() ):
                        the_post(); ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a> 

                        <!-- fourth loop : the rest -->
                    <?php
                        if ( ++$count == 5 and have_posts() ):
                            while ( have_posts() ):
                                the_post(); ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        <?php
                            endwhile;
                        else: // fourth loop has no posts
                        endif;
                    endwhile;
                else: // third loop has no posts
                endif;
            endwhile;
        else: // second loop has no posts
        endif;
    else: // first loop has no posts
    endif;
?>
```

A more elegant solution would be something along these lines:

```
<?php
    $page_counts = array(1, 2, 5, 9999);
    foreach ($page_counts as $iteration => $max_count) {
        $count = $max_count;
        while ( have_posts() and $count-- ) {
            the_post(); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="" ><?php the_title(); ?></a> 
    <?php
        } else break; // No more posts to grab!
    }
?>
```

Again, untested, may contain a mismatching brace or something.

Comment: but post is duplicate in 4 loop i want to avoid duplicate posts

Comment: Are you sure? You're not rewinding the loop between posts, so there should be no reason for the appearance of duplicate posts, unless your original query contains them. What is the original query?

Comment: this is a archive page

Comment: It's still a regular loop, and it's not being rewinded, again, what is the orginal query for the page `var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);`

Comment: please have a look http://pastebin.com/4YgsAZjM

Comment: yeah 

please have a look i tried your code on a test site

http://alturl.com/cyiuk

it's working fine 

but you can see there are duplicate post 

see after this line 
"fourth loop : the rest -- ज्योतिष भी कहता है सरकार मे भारी उथल पुथल होगी"

i dont want all post after this above line which are duplicates

Comment: Please dump the original query for the page. For all I know those may be revisions...

Comment: where can i find the orginal query for the archive page ? which file is

Comment: this is original archive.php file code http://pastebin.com/GDCrcYYT

Comment: add this `var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);` to the top of the template that gets called for that archive page of yours; it appears to me that you don't know what your template code is doing, I can't help you if you don't guide me around your code, the first pastebin you pasted is a complete mess to me.

Comment: is there any another way ?

Comment: Sure, learn [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php) and study the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page) to better understand your code, what you're trying to achieve and how it is we are to help you. Because right, an answer was provided that does what you asked it to do in its own context, your context turned out to be quite different (and messy), I personally can't help you if you don't know what your code is doing at the moment; personally, I know what my code does. Best of luck.

Comment: @Soulseekah I have tried this code on my index page of the default WordPress twentyeleven theme. It seems that once a while loop exhausts the posts, the next while posts starts from the beginning. I didn't expect it to do this - but perhaps this is the explanation for the problem is experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

For your 4th loop you can possibly use another query_post and offset by 7 (the first 7 posts in your other loops)..which will display the remaining posts.

like so:

```
<?php query_posts('offset=7'); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: ok & how to limit the 5 posts in 3 third loop ?

Comment: Probably just set this in your first query_post:
'<?php query_posts('showposts=7'); ?>'

Comment: there are syntax error